# Fourier transform of surface measure, did I get it right?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, spherical-harmonics

I am trying to understand the Fourier transform of the surface measure.
Here is the definition:
If $d\sigma$ is the surface measure on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, then
$$\widehat{d\sigma}(\xi):=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} e^{-\imath \theta\cdot\xi}\,d\theta.$$

So, in dimension $n=2$, 
$$\widehat{d\sigma}(\xi):=\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-\imath \left(\xi_{1}\cos{\theta}+\xi_{2}\sin{\theta}\right)}
\,d\theta,$$

and in dimension $n=3$,

$$\widehat{d\sigma}(\xi):=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-\imath 
\left(\xi_{1}\sin{\theta}\cos{\varphi}+\xi_{2}\sin{\theta}\sin{\varphi}+
\xi_{3}\cos{\varphi}\right)}
\,\sin{\theta}
d\theta\,d\varphi$$

and so on.  Correct?